# Can the first “is” be omitted in the following sentence from Cosmos? “The only planet we are sure is inhabited is a tiny rock...”

Tags: embedded-clauses

Can the sentence be rewritten as “The only planet we are sure of being inhabited is a tiny rock...”?

Comment: I don't know if your rewrite is "wrong" but it sounds awkward to me

Comment: The rewrite seems to imply that *we* are what is being inhabited, not the planet.